# What is the Big-O Notation of this code?

Tags: c++, big-o

What is the Big-O Notation of this code ?

```
for(int i=0; i<10; ++i) 
    for(int a=0; a<n; ++a){
        cout << "*";
        cout << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This one is `O(n)`: the 10 of the outer loop is just a constant.

Comment: Is it equal to 40n + 42 ? or something like that ?

Comment: @faressoft With big-O you drop all constants, and keep only `n`s. `O(40n+42)` is `O(n)`.

Comment: I know that, but what is the total of constat ? Is it 40n+42 ? I want to understand how to calculate the constants too for our exam :(

Comment: @faressoft I can see where the forty is coming from (`a<n`, `++a`, and the two outputs give us four, times ten it's forty), but I do not see the `42`: `i<10`, `++i`, and `a=0` give us 30, `i=0` is another one, so I think the total is `40n+31`.

Answer (score 3):

It's `O(10*n)` which is `O(n)` because 10 is constant coefficient.

Answer (score 0):

The big Oh is: O(10*n) -> O(n)